What does $\mathrm{d}(x^2)$ mean in the $\int_a^bf(x)\, \mathrm{d}(x^2)$ or is such a thing not valid
Here is my understanding of the $\int_a^bf(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$:
\begin{align}
\int_a^bf(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b - a}{n} [f(a) + f(a + h) +... + f(a + (n-1)h)]
\end{align}
where $h = \frac{b - a}{n}$, that is, we have divided the interval $[a, b]$ into
"$n$" infinitely-small intervals of length $h$.
Thus if we see $\int_a^bf(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ we can write it as a summation as described above and also visualise it as summing up rectangles of length $f(x)$ and width $h$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$.
Now my question is how would we write $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}(x^2)$ as a summation and how would we visualise it, or does this type of integral not even exist or can't be calculated?

see this and $\int_a^bf(x)d(x^2)=2\int_a^b xf(x)dx$

In a more general context, the symbol
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d} g(x)
$$
is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral (Wikipedia). We define it as so:

Let $P$ be a partition $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ of $[a,b]$, so that $x_0 = a < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b$.
We say this partition has norm or mesh $\|P\| := \max |x_i-x_{i-1}|$.
Let $\Xi := \{\xi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a collection of "tag" points in the induced subintervals, i.e. $\xi_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$.
We define a Riemann-Stieltjes sum, with respect to the partition, the tags, $f$, and $g$ by
$$
S(f,g,P,\Xi) := \sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i) \Big[ g(x_i) - g(x_{i-1}) \Big]
$$
Then we say that the integral exists with value $I$ if, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $\|P\| < \delta$ then $|S(f,g,P,\Xi) - I| < \varepsilon$; this may be sometimes written as
$$
\lim_{\|P\| \to 0} S(f,g,P,\Xi) = I
$$

This is precisely the definition of the Riemann integral, in the narrow case where $g(x) = x$

Note: Your phrasing of the definition is a little restrictive, and makes assumptions on the tags and partition. In particular, you're assuming that the partition points are equally spaced, with tag points on the left-endpoints of the intervals, i.e.
$$\begin{align*}
x_k &= a + k \Delta x \text{ for } k=0,1,2,\cdots,n \\
\xi_k &= x_{k-1} \\
\Delta x &= \frac{b-a}{n}
\end{align*}$$
Then for that particular case the Riemann-Stieltjes sum is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f \left( a + (i-1) \frac{b-a}{n} \right) \left[ g \left( a + i \frac{b-a}{n} \right) - g \left( a + (i-1) \frac{b-a}{n} \right) \right]
$$
Sadly, nothing that can factor out of the sum this time, unless $g$ is special.

In particular, if

$f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$
$g$ is monotone
$g'$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$

we have the result that
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x)
= \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
which is probably natural to you if you remember the definition of a differential as $\mathrm{d}h := h'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$.

It seems worth noting that the particular case of interest would be $g(x)=x^2$. That may or may not be monotonic depending on the interval $[a,b]$, so whether $d(x^2)$ makes sense can't be assessed without that context.

@Semiclassical Not really. If $a< 0 < b$ then $$\int_a^b f(x) dx^2 = \int_a^0 f(x) dx^2 + \int_0^b f(x) dx^2 = 2\int_a^0x f(x) dx + 2\int_0^bx f(x) dx = 2\int_a^b x f(x) dx $$
